# Google Cloud Platform - App Engine , splitting Traffic

Tags: google-app-engine

**Point 1** - Suppose we have 2 services hosted on App Engine
(1) Service /default
(2) Service /my-first-custom-service

**Point 2** - Now I have 2 different versions on which services are hosted
(1) Service /default                        : Version=V1
(2) Service /my-first-custom-service        : Version=V10

**Point 3** - Now I move to service folder  "/my-first-custom-service" , and type below command

> gcloud app browse --versions=v10
> and suppose I get a below url :
> **url :** http//v10/url

**Actual Question** - Now if I hit the url , why is default service value is returned and not the output of my-first-custom-service. I understand if version names are same then obviously default active version should hit. But here the services as well as versions , both are different and hence no chance of conflict . Then also default service output is generated.

I know we can solve this by below command , where we specify service name . But I think its not needed if there is no conflict and we are in exclusive folder of /my-first-custom-service

> gcloud app browse --service="my-first-custom-service"

Comment: What you are experiencing is the intended functionality of App Engine. You should consider raising a feature request for it

Comment: As it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/browse) this is the intended functionality of App Engine, I suggest you to raise a feature request for this situation in the [issuetracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) by selecting the "Create a new App Engine issue" option in the Compute section